# Comparing a tuple in a list with another tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples. I want to pick each and every tuple in the list and compare it with another tuple which is defined by me.

The code that i used is as follows;

```
list1 = [(3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]
for item in list1:
   if list1[item] == (4,5)
      print ("OK")
```

but it says that list indices must be an integer or slice. If i want to take each tuple in the list and compare them against another, how should i code it?

please help me!

Comment: Please resend with correct indentation and send the traceback.

Comment: The reason for the error message is that you are expecting `for item in list:` to set `item` to a series of *numbers* that you then use as list subscripts in `list1[item]`. But that isn't how `for...in` works. The first time through the loop, `item` isn't `0`, it is  `list1[0]`. That is why the interpreter is complaining that it is expecting an integer: `list1[item]` is the same as `list1[(4,5)]`. And what you really want is `(4,5)`. So, as one answer points out, change `list1[item]` to `item`.

Comment: @BoarGules - A Pretty good explanation... i got the point and thanks to you! I'm still a python beginner and your ideas are inspiring me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need for loop **IF** you have **only one** tuple to check . Just directly check using `if`

```
tpl = (4,5) # Single user defined tuple
if tpl in list1:
    print ("OK")
```

If you have **many** tuples to check

```
tuplst = [(3,4), (1,2)] # List of tuples
list1 = [(3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]

for tpl in tuplst:
    if tpl in list1:
        print ("OK")
```

The problem in your code was that when you do `list1[item]`, you are trying to do `list1[(3, 4)]` which is not the correct way to index a list and hence you get the `IndexError`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
list1 = [(3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]
for item in list1:
    if item == (4,5):
        print ("OK")
```

Answer (score 1):

you could just test if the tuple (`(4, 5)` in the example below) is in the list:

```
if (4, 5) in list1:
    print('OK')
```

there is no need for an explicit loop.

if you have multiple tuples to check against, i suggest you use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set)s:

```
cmp = set(((4, 5), (5, 6)))
if cmp < set(list1):
    print('OK')
```

this checks if *both* tuples appear at least once in your original list.

Comment: Depends on the actual program, if you want repeats, this won't work as intended.

Comment: @SVengat not sure i understand... what would be repeated and therefore not work?

Comment: As in, this program will not be suitable if you want to print("Ok") for every occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it the following way..

```
list1 = [(3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6)]
for item in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[item] == (4,5):
        print ("OK")
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: there are better ways to loop over containers in Python. you could for example do `for tup in list1:`

Comment: that is true, this is the solution which came to mind quickest. mind to post this in another answer? I gladly vote it up

Comment: @Cut7er  I appreciate your effort! Thanx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution:

```
for i in list1:
    if i==(4,5):
        print("Ok")
    else:
        ....
```